# SQL PK Lookup with Extra Column

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have two MySQL tables like this:

```
User
 Id (PK, auto-increment integer)

Subscriber
 Id (PK, auto-increment integer)
 OwnerId (FK to User.Id)
 Name
```

Since I am making queries on the PK, is there a performance difference between these two:

```
UPDATE Subscriber SET Name = 'John' WHERE Id = 20;
UPDATE Subscriber SET Name = 'John' WHERE Id = 20 and OwnerId = 50;
```

Ideally I'd like to also pass the OwnerId as an extra precaution (it's a multi-tenant application). Is this necessary?

In terms of performance (assuming I keep the WHERE conditions in order - with the PK first) how can I benchmark this, or see the execution plan on MySQL - are there any performance optimizations the engine makes that I should be aware of? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not **necessary** to add an additional filter, there is a **difference**.

```
UPDATE Subscriber SET Name = 'John' WHERE Id = 20 and OwnerId = 50;
```

`Subscriber.Id` is the primary key, therefore it has unique values and the clause `WHERE Id = 20` can only ever select one single row.

The *only* possible effect of the additional clause `AND OwnerId = 50` in this example can be to prohibit the UPDATE, if `50` should not be the value of `Subscriber.OwnerId` in the same row.

While this is hardly relevant for performance (primary key is indexed, index search will return a single row in either case), it also does not make an awful lot of sense for most use cases.

You can test the execution with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html). [More info in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: I understand the results of the query. I am only concerned with the performance between the two.

Comment: @Harper: I was still at it. Last part is about performance and execution plan.

Comment: @Harper correctness should always win over performance. Especially when the performance difference will be small.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the PK in your where clause both statements will update the same row. You only profit from the extra precaution if another job could modify the row between your SELECT statement that searched the ID and your update. If you never change the OwnerId after you created a Subscriber you can ignore the OwnerId from the UPDATE statement.

You can get the execution plan for SELECT statements with the EXPLAIN keyword (see the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)). To see what your update uses is not directly possible. But if you make a SELECT statement with the same fields and the same WHERE clause you should get a comparable output.